# unable to install kernel 6.5.2 in 22.04

Tags: kernel, 22.04

Using 22.04LTS I am unable to install kernel 6.5.2. I get this message:

```
    Finding latest version available on kernel.ubuntu.com
    Latest version is: v6.5.2, continue? (y/N)
    Abort, the amd64 build has not succeeded
```

As written [here](https://ubuntuhandbook.org/index.php/2023/08/linux-kernel-6-5-released-how-to-install-it-in-ubuntu/), I did (in terminal): sudo apt install linux-oem-22.04d and get as output:

```
    linux-oem-22.04d is already the newest version (6.5.0.1003.3)
```

Comment: According to https://kernel.ubuntu.com/~kernel-ppa/mainline/v6.5.2/ it is showing that the build for the 6.5.2 is failing on AMD64 but it is passing on the arm64.  The Kernel is not ready for AMD64 installation yet.  As far as the `linux-oem-22.04d` installation goes, the version of 6.5.0-1003 is all that it does install.  Are you experiencing issues with the supported 6.2 kernel that now works with 22.04?

Comment: Thanks for the response. As it is now I'll just wait

Answer (score 1):

Generally there is very little gain in hunting the bleeding edge kernel versions.

It often leads to at least some small problems with driver compatibility or similar, at times something breaks and leaves you "on your own" to solve it, or having to wait for someone else to do it.

*If you still insist, try following instructions here:

https://9to5linux.com/you-can-now-install-linux-kernel-6-5-on-ubuntu-heres-how*

*Another alternative:

https://ubuntuhandbook.org/index.php/2023/09/linux-kernel-6-5-is-ready-to-install-in-ubuntu-22-04-lts/*